# Chrome update has messed up my debugging with VS

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome

From yesterday to today I am not able to launch in localhost my project as it seems that my non-secure chrome has updated to version Versión 94.0.4606.61 (Build oficial) (x86_64) and when I launch my hybrid app where its supposed to do an auto-login before was a 200 response now its a 302 and does a redirect.

What can be the issue here?

This is my **launch.json**

```
{
"configurations": [{
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
    "url": "http://localhost:8100/#/Home/dashboardApp",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "--args",
        "--disable-web-security",
        "--allow-file-access-from-files",
        "--allow-running-insecure-content",
        "--ignore-certificate-errors",
        "--disable-features=SameSiteByDefaultCookies,CookiesWithoutSameSiteMustBeSecure",
    ],
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
}]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- - Download the older version of Chromium Chrome.

https://github.com/macchrome/macstable/releases/download/v93.0.4577.82-r902210-Ungoogled-macOS/Chromium.app.ungoogled-93.0.4577.82.zip

2- Put the .app in your application finder.

3- Add this to your visual code launch.json (inside "configurations")
"runtimeExecutable": "/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium"

4-  If you can't open Chromiun, head over to System Preferences, Security / Privacy, and General.

Important note, the extension debugger for chrome is deprecated, uninstall it. Use VS Code's internal debubbuger.

Comment: You should download a chromium version before 82 which is when the samesite cookie was removed.